# Spring Tool Suite 4.19.1 How to modify the Context root

Tags: spring

In Earlier versions of Spring Tool Suite (e.g. 4.2.2), the Properties popup included an entry in the left menu entitled "Web Project settings" where you could change the name of the Context root.

I am currently trying to set up a project in STS 4.19.1, but this selection is no longer present.

Has anyone been using the newer versions of STS and what is the best way to change to Context root in STS 4.19.1 version?

This app is not a Spring Boot App!

Thanks for your help.

I opened the Properties link by right clicking the Git project project1-web entry in STS 4.19.1 Package Explorer. There are the usual Builders, Deployment Assembly Java Build Path entries there that I would expect to see, but the "Web Project Settings" entry is no longer there. I want to change the Context root of the web project from project1-web to just project1.

I have searched the web for an answer on how this is done in later versions of STS, but to no avail.